# Group rows by the largest grouping columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a time like this

| Item | title | image | hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | cat | cat_x.jpg | x-123 |
| B | cat | cat_y.jpg | y-123 |
| C | dog1 | dog.jpg | xyx |
| D | dog2 | dog.jpg | xyx |

I can group items by the same title, image or hash column and have an array with groupped items.

For example, A and B could be grouped by title

```
SELECT 
  title,
  array_agg(item) AS items
FROM products
GROUP BY 1
```

| title | items |
| --- | --- |
| cat | {A,B} |
| dog1 | {C} |
| dog2 | {D} |

but this is not good for C and D which should be grouped by image (dog.jpg)

```
SELECT 
      image,
      array_agg(item) AS items
    FROM products
    GROUP BY 1
```

| image | items |
| --- | --- |
| cat_x.jpg | {A} |
| cat_y.jpg | {B} |
| dog.jpg | {C,D} |

and the same for "hash" column.

So if two rows have the same title, or image or hash (or all) should be merged into the same group. If two groups have at least one item in common, they need to merged into the same group.

If X and Y are grouped by title, and Y and Z are grouped by image. Then X,Y,Z should be into the same array.

In the end, I don't want two groups containing the same item.
Each Item should belong to only one group.

An idea could be:

1. Group items by title
2. Then group the result by image
3. Then group the result by hash

Products table contains about 100,000 records.

**My progress so far**

At the moment I tried with this but for 100,000 records it timeouts. Even if I am using temp tables + indexes.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v4RsA4jRdYz3JHmph3Mykj/1

```
create temp table titles AS (
    
      SELECT
    
        title,
        array_agg(item) AS items
        
      FROM products
      GROUP BY 1
 
);
create temp table images AS (
    
      SELECT
    
        image,
        array_agg(item) AS items
        
      FROM products
      GROUP BY 1
 
);
create temp table hashes AS (
    
      SELECT
    
        hash,
        array_agg(item) AS items
        
      FROM products
      GROUP BY 1
 
);
CREATE INDEX idx_items_titles on titles USING GIN ("items");   
CREATE INDEX idx_items_images on images USING GIN ("items");   
CREATE INDEX idx_items_hashes on hashes USING GIN ("items");   


SELECT 

    ARRAY( SELECT DISTINCT e FROM unnest(items || title_items || hash_items) AS a(e) )
    
FROM images,
LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        titles.items AS title_items
    FROM titles
    WHERE titles.items && images.items
) x,
LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        hashes.items AS hash_items
    FROM hashes
    WHERE hashes.items && images.items
) y


GROUP BY 1
```

**Desired output**

| Groups |
| --- |
| {B,A} |
| {D,C} |

---

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: What if `A` and `B` have the same title, `B` and `C` have the same image, but `A` and `C` share no values in any column. Do you still want to lump them into the same group?

Comment: In this case A,B,C all in the same array (group).

Comment: @Bohemian You can find desired output in the db-fiddle above.

Comment: @sparkle please edit your question to show the desired output given your sample data. The db-fiddle link is handy, but the question should stand alone without it; visitors should be able to grasp the question you're asking without having to visit external sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lateral joins and the array columns look very expensive.

I would instead use a different approach where you add an extra column for the representative element of the respective group, like in a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

A simple definition of a canonical representation for each row might be the smallest id of any other row that shares either the same image, title or hash. Using a window function, we can easily (and efficiently) compute that:

```sql
SELECT
  array_agg(item) AS items,
  array_agg(DISTINCT title) AS titles,
  array_agg(DISTINCT image) AS images,
  array_agg(DISTINCT hash) AS hashes
FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAST (
    MIN(item) OVER (PARTITION BY title),
    MIN(item) OVER (PARTITION BY image),
    MIN(item) OVER (PARTITION BY hash)
  ) AS group_id
  FROM products
) AS tmp
GROUP BY tmp.group_id;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=265b43a43b91f68f9e81514d81270733) on your sample data)</sup>
Unfortunately, it is also wrong, since it doesn't handle transitive equivalence. You can check [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=995b49e33a7ce1eef29607ffda9df5f3), where `A` and `D` contain no shared values, but they do both share some values (their titles) with other rows that have the same value for another column (their images).

To fix this issue, one will need to actually run the union-find algorithm, repeatedly merging the groups until you end up with the desired equivalence classes. [This is not exactly trivial](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/the-sql-of-membership-equivalence-classes-cliques/), but can be done with a recursive common table expression:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE eqiv AS (
  SELECT id, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY title) AS group_id
  FROM products
UNION
  SELECT id, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY image) AS group_id
  FROM products
UNION
  SELECT id, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY hash) AS group_id
  FROM products
),
rel AS (
  SELECT id, id AS group_id
  FROM products
UNION
  SELECT eqiv.id, rel.group_id
  FROM rel
  JOIN eqiv ON (rel.id = eqiv.group_id)
)
SELECT
  array_agg(id) AS items,
  array_agg(DISTINCT title) AS titles,
  array_agg(DISTINCT image) AS images,
  array_agg(DISTINCT hash) AS hashes
FROM products
GROUP BY (SELECT MIN(group_id) FROM rel WHERE rel.id = products.id);
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bacee52fd8724a33f341c6c6ca5121ef))</sup>

Comment: It works great for few products (<1,000) but for large dataset (100,000) it takes more 200sec. We know that grouping by hash first and then image and title could be faster. How can we use this info to edit the query?

Comment: Which one, the first or the second? I'm not sure about your data, do you actually need to the transitive equivalence?

Comment: 2nd. For example, if we group by hash first we pass from 100K to 26K rows, then going grouping by same image, then titles. Yes, transitive equivalence but after two items have been put in the same group we are sure we won't change them. At most, we'll add other items into the group.

Comment: Actually, maybe I am looking that we don't really need transitive equivalence and the option 1 is really fast (<1s) and fits our case. Let me make a few more checks. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if the recursive query could be sped up by some extra constraints (such as putting `WHERE id <> group_id` on each `equiv`) to reduce the number of rows, or maybe even making `equiv` a temp table with an appropriate index, or changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` to avoid deduplication - I'd take a look at the query plan to see what part is so slow.

Comment: Also I wonder if there's a good way to implement the real union-find algorithm in sql